# Keep 2 years of records in table when reference column is in a string format

Tags: date

I want to keep 2 years of records in table but client wants to keep the reference column(ReferencePeriod) is in a string format.

So it's working when the column is in a Date format:

DELETE
FROM dbo.GSUFVerification_TestMylene
WHERE ReferencePeriod < DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE())

But I can't make it work converting the column upfront.  I feel really stupid right now :-(

Can you help me out please?

Comment: Try WHERE CAST(ReferencePeriod as date) ... Do it with a SELECT first though. As long as all values are valid dates, it should work

Comment: Great! Thanks :-)